# Use Regex condition to create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my problem.

I know how to create a boolean column based on RegEx, like this:

```
df['New Column'] = df.columnA.str.match(regex)
```

In this example, 'New Column' will be contain True or False values.

But how do I do if I want to use a condition to say "If my RegEx returns true, push "this" value, and if it returns False, then push "that" value.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `where()` function from NumPy:

```
df['New Column'] = np.where(df.columnA.str.match(regex), "this", "that")
```

You can use other column names instead of the scalars:

```
df['New Column'] = np.where(df.columnA.str.match(regex), df.columnB, df.columnC)
```

Comment: Hello again @DYZ. How can I do if want to process multiple possibilities and not just a binary condition? How can I use my own function, like for instance "return myfunction(df.columnA)" ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok I just made a test and it's easy, I just need to call my function with the column in argument and it works. Pyhon is definitely magic.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already got the series of booleans, why not a simple `map`?

```
df['New Column'] = list(map(lambda b : 'this' if b else 'that', df.foo.str.match('foo.')))
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

```
df['New Column'] = ["this" if row.str.match(regex) else "that" for row in df.columnA]
```